# ejercicio basico python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sublimetext3

Tengo un problema con unas lineas que escribí.

Escribí estas lineas:

```
letra = input("introduce una letra: ")


def xd():
    verdad = False
    if letra in ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]:
        verdad = True
    else:
        verdad = False
    return verdad


print(xd())
```

Y funciona bien, el tema es que cuando lo ejecuto e ingreso la "d" me aparece lo siguiente:

```
def function(self):
```

Por que pasa eso?

Comment: Hola, Facu Sanchez, te doy la bienvenida a [es.so]. El código que muestras es correcto excepto por errores de identación y porque falta `:` al final de la linea `if letra in....` (supongo que al copiarlo aquí). ¿Es todo tu código en el script? ¿es todo lo que te aparece al ejecutarlo?¿Es una excepción?¿te imprime el retorno de la función ( "verdad")?

Comment: Hola!, los errores de identación y aparecieron cuando trascribi el codigo acá, en ST están bien escrito.
 La idea del programa es que tengo que escribir una fución que al ingresar una letra me devuelva True si es una vocal o False si no lo es, pero no entiendo porque cuando lo ejecuto si ingreso una letra como la "i", "d", "w" me aparecen las opciones para ingresar "if", "def", "while"...deberia agregar algo para que eso no suceda?

Comment: Facu  lo he corregido, mira que lo tengas así de todas formas (deberias usar 4 espacios para identar si no lo estás haciendo). De cualquier forma, lo que muestras no tiene nada que ver con tu código, o tienes más código que no muestras o es un problema de st,  por eso te comentaba que agregues más contexto. Aparte de lo que preguntaba arriba ¿Lo ejecutas en la consola integrada de st o en la consola del sistema?

Comment: Muchas gracias! la identación st la hace sola, y en cuanto al codigo, eso es todo.
Uso el REPL de sublime para ejecutarlo, quizas sea problema del editor, voy a probar actualizandolo

Answer (score 1):

Si estas trabajando en Sublime Text, al ejecutar el programa e introducir la "d" automaticamente rellena con lo que dices lo unico que debes hacer es tocar el boton de "Retroceso" o borrar y ya esta.
Esto que te sucede es debido a que Sublime Text autocompleta palabras.

Answer (score 0):

No soy un experto, pero parece que estas dejando el parámetro de la función vacío prueba a escribir
Def xd(n) que es el parámetro que le pasas
Resto de código 
Y cuando hagas el print (xd(letra)) en tu caso.
Puede que sea por eso

Answer (score 0):

Amigo no te compliques, échale un ojo al siguiente código, pues el tuyo es bastante redundante:

```
def xd():
    letra = input("introduce una letra: ")
    print(letra in ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Te paso cómo lo haría, habiendo probado que se ejecuta bien:

```
letra = input("introduce una letra: ")
def xd(l):
    verdad = False
    if l in ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]:
        verdad = True
    return verdad
print(xd(letra))
```

([Acá va un link con el código](http://pythontutor.com/live.html#code=letra%20%3D%20input%28%22introduce%20una%20letra%3A%20%22%29%0Adef%20xd%28letra%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20verdad%20%3D%20False%0A%20%20%20%20if%20letra%20in%20%5B%22a%22,%20%22e%22,%20%22i%22,%20%22o%22,%20%22u%22%5D%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20verdad%20%3D%20True%0A%20%20%20%20return%20verdad%0Aprint%28xd%28letra%29%29%0A&cumulative=false&curInstr=0&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-live.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false))

2 observaciones:

1°, es importante que a la función le pases un parámetro (lo que va entre paréntesis). El parámetro es el valor que vos le das como entrada a la función, para que opere con eso y te devuelva una salida. En éste caso es l , la letra que tiene que evaluar.
Por fuera de la función, vos creaste una variable que se llama letra, a la que le pusiste la "d" con input. Después al final del código "llamás" a la función, y le pasas como parámetro entre paréntesis esa variable.

2°, no te hace falta el else: verdad=false, dado que vos estableciste que verdad es false al principio de la función, y solamente va a ser true si se cumple la condición de que la letra esté en la lista de vocales (sino, el valor de verdad no cambia, sigue siendo false).

Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

bienvenido.
Te dejo una versión mas limpia del código.

1. No es necesario que asignes booleanos para el resultado, solo retorna la comparación
2. Las cadenas de texto en python se pueden usar como listas
3. Recuerda que pides una letra fuera de la definición del método y debes pasarla como parámetro

   ```
   def xd(l):
     return l in 'aeiou'

   letra = Input('Introduce una letra: ')
   xd(letra)
   ```